# how to use XMLRPC in iphone?

Tags: xml, xml-rpc, iphone

I want to integrate XMLRPC in iphone.but not able to understand what to do?any one have its information or tutorial or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this XML-RPC framework https://github.com/corristo/xmlrpc .